# Selenium code in PyCharm(Python) running slow, how to improve speed?

Tags: python, performance, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

I wrote this automated bot in PyCharm and I do not know why my code executes so slow? Any help for improvement is sincerely appreciated.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from InfoApp import keys
import time
def order(k):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='driver/chromedriver')
    driver.get(k['product_url'])
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="RightRail"]/div/div[4]/fieldset/div/div[7]/label').click()
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1000)")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="floating-atc-wrapper"]/div/button').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="PDP"]/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/button[2]').click()
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="nav-cart"]/a/div/span').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div[4]/button').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="qa-guest-checkout"]').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="firstName"]').send_keys(k["First_Name"])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    order(keys)
```

Comment: It has unnecessary time.sleep which can be changed to use webdriver waits.

Comment: I added the time.sleep because the page was not fully loaded and I have a line of syntax to scroll down the page and click, it was not finding the button as the page was not fully loaded so I added the time.sleep. So instead of  time.sleep i should use  driver.implicitly_wait(5)?

Comment: Pretty much time sleep is never used in automation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**remove time.sleep and add explicit or implicit wait:**

you can add implicit wait as

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='driver/chromedriver')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

this will automatically make all commands to wait maximum of 10 seconds . If element not found in 10 sec then element not found is thrown.

but this will not check clicability , visibility etc , this checks only for presence of element. For other condition you can use explicit wait.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

elem= wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'somelocator')))
```

### Note:

There is good video link jeff added but to add to that :

**implicit waits are not bad practices, mixing implicit wait and explicit wait is bad practice. As implict wait waits for only the presence of the elment so in most cases you cannot avoid explicit wait as you need to wait for visibility,clicability etc . so its better to avoid it completely as it cause long waits in your code when you mix both implicit and explicit wait together**

### So if you are using explicit wait DONT use implict wait

Comment: Please don't add a line of hyphens in your answers. It adds a whole sentence of large bolded text.

Comment: Implicit waits are a bad practice according to several Selenium contributors including Simon Stewart, Selenium project lead. See his seleniumconf talk: https://youtu.be/gyfUpOysIF8?t=2200. Explicit waits should be used instead.

Comment: @JeffC implicit waits are not bad practices, mixing implicit wait and explicit wait is bad practice. As implict wait for only the presence of the elment so its better to avoid it completely as it cause long waits in your code when you mix both together. So as you cannot avoid explicit wait you should not be using implicit wait

Comment: No. Watch the video. Simon is the guy that wrote the implicit wait code and he clearly said don't use it... use WebDriverWait instead.